# Help understanding Accidental Noise Gradient function

Tags: interpolation, terrain-rendering, perlin-noise

**Background**:

I am trying to create a set of functions to manipulate noise, similar to Libnoise, Fastnoise and the Accidental Noise Library. The end goal is to produce terrain.

As recommended by this article (http://accidentalnoise.sourceforge.net/minecraftworlds.html) I am starting out with a 'Gradient' function.  Quoting the author:

> The Gradient function is given a line-segment in N-dimensional space
>   (ie, in whatever coordinate space we are working in, be it 2D, 3D, or
>   higher) and calculates a gradient field aligned along this segment.
>   Input coordinates are projected on this line, and their gradient value
>   is calculated depending where on the line they lie in relation to the
>   endpoints of the defining segment.

Even after repeatedly reading the article and looking at these two other questions I found ([2D Terra(ria)in generation - Accidental noise](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57715/2d-terrariain-generation-accidental-noise) and [Accidental noise - Gradient function](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57790/accidental-noise-gradient-function)) I'm still having problems understanding exactly what the function is doing.

**Questions**:

1. My test chunk is of size 32x32x32 and ranges from -16 to +16 on the x, y and z axis.  In this case, would the inputs to the function be x/32, y/32, z/32?
2. Does the function map points between 0 and 1 (as input) to a point between 1 and -1 (as output)? I.e if my x, y and z where -16, -16, -16, would I get 1, 1, 1 back?
3. Why in the extract below is the line segment (0,1)->(0,0) rather than (0,0)->(0,1)?  Given that the example line segment is defined as x1=0, x2=0, y1=0, y2=1.

> The Gradient function accepts a line segment in the form of (x1,x2,
>   y1,y2) for the 2D case, extended to (x1,x2, y1,y2, z1,z2) for the 3D
>   case. The point formed by (x1,y1) delineates the start of the line
>   segment, which is mapped to 0. The point formed by (x2,y2) is the end
>   of the line segment that maps to 1. So here we are mapping the line segment (0,1)->(0,0) to the gradient.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm not sure why you're asking game developers about this.

Comment: @Almo I'm trying to implement noise manipulation techniques to supplement the procedural terrain generation system for the game I'm developing.  The two questions I linked on this topic were asked and answered on this site.

Comment: It's still a poorly constructed question for our format. It's conversational, and doesn't ask one question with a well-defined answer. Instead it reads like a forum post.

Comment: @Almo are there specific edits you'd recommend to help focus it better for our format? Constructive feedback or edit proposals can go a long way to improving a question.